# Jquery drag and drop table rows and groups of table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, html-table

I have records listed on my ruby on rails application in table format. The records or table rows are actually grouped into groups of records. I indicate this to the user by having different shaded background colors of the rows.

I need to be able to drag and drop `<TR>`'s or table rows from one group of rows to another. Ideally, when you're dragging the row and are over another group, it sort of outlines/highlights that group to indicate you're about to drop into that group.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You should really look at the latest RailsCasts episode for calendars. It is taking a lot of concepts that you're using and putting them in application. You would use the assets jquery-ui plugin and include the styling and javascript in your application files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say highlight the group title when dropping into a group. Ensure the title of a group is always on the page by using some javascript to make the last group title row that went off the top of the page to always appear (fixed at the top).